# Duplicate value in part-r-00000

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

While i am processing an xml file(https://github.com/studhadoop/xml/blob/master/rpt) i am getting duplicate values as output.

```
bin/hadoop fs -text /user/root/t-output1/part-r-00000
ST17925 1.02
ST17925 1.02
ST17926 3.00
ST17926 3.00
ST17927 3.00
ST17927 3.00
```

my mapred https://github.com/studhadoop/xml/blob/master/XmlParser11.java

Why is it so? Whether it depends on the size of xml file? Whwn i am having a large xml file, iget duplicated values. but if it is a small xml file ,the output is ok.
**UPDATED 1**

One more doubt.
instead of listing like this

```
studentid grade
ST17925 1.02
ST17926 3.00
ST17927 3.00
```

what change should i make in my program?

**UPDATE 2**
How will i make my output in csv format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in your reducer implementation, you write the key for every value to the output collector:

```
   for (Text value : values) {
      context.write(key, value);
    }
```

What you probably wanted is this:

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 for (Text value : values) {
    sb.append(value.toString());
    sb.append(" ");
 }
 context.write(key, new Text(sb.toString());
```

Which will generate a space separated list of every value per key.

Comment: I originally had the same thought, but i think he's more interested in why the values are duplicated for each key

Comment: @ChrisWhite ouch, yes that might be another interpretation.

Comment: ys u r right, but i need to know why the id and grade is repeating.my file rpt contains only 1 entry for these id.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut: why would the fist piece of code duplicate it, I see no point of duplication there?